# Android studio- error:cannot find symbol variable raw

Tags: android, android-resources

I was trying to do simple code in my class which involves adding a short `mp3` clip into the `raw folder` then using 2 `Buttons` start and stop to play the audio.

**Here is the process i followed in creating the raw folder:**

1. I click the res folder.
2. I right clicked res-new-folder-res folder
3. I ticked the "change folder location" `Button` and changed the location from "res/2" to "res/raw".

Then I simply copied the `song1.mp3` file and paste it into the raw file.

When I pressed the run program `Button` it told me `error:cannot find symbol variable raw`.

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yp8F.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it like:

```
MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.class,getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.song1));
```

Comment: I am really new to this so could you be more specific where should i add that line of code?

Comment: Thank you. I will try it with that let you know

Answer (score 0):

Clean and build your project to fixe this problem.

Comment: Sorry Mavis, I am very new to this. Could you be more specific and go into further details about what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Just Clean the project that will help

Follow the image below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my layout file was in app/src/debug/res/layout   but it should be in app/src/main/res/layout. the difference is src/debug and src/main folder.